# Sony Vaio S dual boot issue

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, vaio

I used usb stick to boot and install Ubuntu in legacy boot option since it did not boot in UFI

Install alongside windows option was not available so I install it manually 
everything went fine but when I tried to use gurb boot repair, it told me to boot in UFI mode.

but when I boot with UFI I get windows.
and when I boot with legacy I get Ubuntu.

can someone help me pls to fix this boot issue
I want windows 7 to be the default boot since I use it most of the time.
I prefer if you give me a flexible solution since I might update to windows 10 in the future and I don't want to lose Ubuntu and reinstall it.

Comment: Update: i tried to use my usb flash and it booted into Ubuntu. so i tried to use gurb boot repair .
i followed the steps and it says that it was fixed.
so i booted but not to gurb but to windows.
so i tried to enter legacy mode but i am getting an error and gurp rescue appear
what should i do now?
can somone help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have installed Ubuntu in legacy mode and Windows in UEFI mode, so you now have to "switch" between OSes using the UEFI menu...  *You cannot use grub to switch between OSes* as that is *unavailable* in UEFI mode as you didn't install it in UEFI mode!

*So, this is **absolutely normal** behaviour for the installation type you've chosen.*

Comment: Thanks for answering but the problem is that , i don't have the option to install Ubuntu beside windows .
Also, if i install Ubuntu manually in EFI mode it will not be bootable even if i try to use gurb fixer.
so , I think the solution is to install gurb bootloader manually which i have some understanding issues with how to do it.

Comment: Like I said: "How do I install Ubuntu in UEFI mode on a Sony Vaio S?" is an [entirely new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) The set-up you now have *cannot* be "fixed" without a re-install...

Comment: Alright,fair enough.
i will search for it. i hope to find it without asking again.
you have my thanks for answering my question.